# R: Creating a loop for two models?

Tags: r, function, loops, model, regression

I currently have following code with two functions that calculate the model fit for two distinct models. The difference is in the *lm* function, where *+ log(v2)* has been added in model 2.

**R code**

```
dat <- data.frame(clicks = runif(30, 1, 100), v1 = runif(30, 1, 100), v2 = runif(30, 1, 100))
p0 <- 1  # number of parameters in lm()
p1 <- 2  # number of parameters in lm()
n <- nrow(dat) - 1

## Model 1 Loop
model1 <- function(x) {
  fit <- lm(log(clicks) ~ log(v1), data = dat, subset = 1:x, model = FALSE)
  pred <- predict(fit, newdata = dat[x+1, ])
  c(summary(fit)$r.squared)
}

## Model 1 Regression
result_m1 <- t(sapply(p0:n, model1))
data.frame(result_m1)

## Model 2 Loop
model2 <- function(x) {
  fit <- lm(log(clicks) ~ log(v1) + log(v2), data = dat, subset = 1:x, model = FALSE)
  pred <- predict(fit, newdata = dat[x+1, ])
  c(summary(fit)$r.squared)
}

## Model 2 Regression
result_m2 <- t(sapply(p1:n, model2))
data.frame(result_m2)
```

**Question**: Can I somehow create a function that implements a loop for the different models only, instead of repeating the calculation for every model?

I have something like this in mind but weren't able to implement it .http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/pages/looping_strings.htm

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a point in recreating a function that can be easily done with model-selection functions in available packages.

```
library(leaps)
library(dplyr)

b <- regsubsets(clicks ~ ., data=dat, nbest=10, nvmax=2) # carries out exhaustive model selection (10 best models; 2 maximum predictors)

coef(b, 1:3) # returns coefficient for the 3 models in this case
[[1]]
(Intercept)          v1 
 60.8067570  -0.2665699 

[[2]]
(Intercept)          v2 
49.96974177 -0.05227489 

[[3]]
(Intercept)          v1          v2 
62.02323816 -0.26422966 -0.02676747 


summary(b)$rsq #provide r.squared value for 3 models
[1] 0.067952759 0.002366681 0.068568059
```

To run prediction is a tad more complicated.

```
all.mods <- summary(b)$which[,-1] # gives logic output of predictors combination
all.mods
     v1    v2
1  TRUE FALSE
1 FALSE  TRUE
2  TRUE  TRUE

RHS <- lapply(seq(nrow(all.mods)), function(m) summary(b)$which[m,-1] %>% which %>% names %>% paste(., collapse="+"))
RHS
[[1]]
[1] "v1"

[[2]]
[1] "v2"

[[3]]
[1] "v1+v2"

lm.form <- lapply(RHS, function(m)parse(text=paste("lm(clicks ~", m, ", data=dat)"))) 
lm.mods <- lapply(lm.form, eval) # return list of all lm.mods generated
```

The list of lm.mods can subsequently be used for `predict` with new.data.